# Realm dotnet where is RealmConfiguration.EncryptionKey

Tags: .net, realm

Looking at the Realm dotnet documentation, it says we can encrypt a realm using

```
var config = new RealmConfiguration("Mine.realm");
config.EncryptionKey = new byte[64] // key MUST be exactly this size
{
  0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08,
  0x11, 0x12, 0x13, 0x14, 0x15, 0x16, 0x17, 0x18,
  0x21, 0x22, 0x23, 0x24, 0x25, 0x26, 0x27, 0x28,
  0x31, 0x32, 0x33, 0x34, 0x35, 0x36, 0x37, 0x38,
  0x41, 0x42, 0x43, 0x44, 0x45, 0x46, 0x47, 0x48,
  0x51, 0x52, 0x53, 0x54, 0x55, 0x56, 0x57, 0x58,
  0x61, 0x62, 0x63, 0x64, 0x65, 0x66, 0x67, 0x68,
  0x71, 0x72, 0x73, 0x74, 0x75, 0x76, 0x77, 0x78
};

var realm = Realm.GetInstance(config);  // will create/open encrypted realm "Mine.realm"
```

The problem is that the RealmConfiguration class does not seem to have a property called EncryptionKey. Is this an extension or is it just missing in v0.74.1. The worrying thing is that the link to the api documentation for RealmConfiguration goes to a 404 page

Can someone from Realm let me know what I am doing wrong, or let me know whether this feature is available in Realm dotnet v0.74.1

Comment: Further investigation - When I select Go to Definition in Visual Studio, the EncryptionKey property is not in listed in the RealmConfiguration class. I looked on Github and EncryptionKey property is in the class. Is it getting optimised out when building the product?

Comment: Also noted ObjectClasses property and ReadOnly public member variable is not listed in VisualStudio

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Realm in a PCL project? I just checked and the [`RealmConfiguration` class in the PCL project](https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet/blob/V0.74.1/Realm.PCL/RealmConfigurationPCL.cs) doesn't have the `EncryptionKey`, `ReadOnly`, `ObjectClasses` and `SchemaVersion` properties, whereas the [actual `RealmConfiguration`](https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet/blob/V0.74.1/Realm.Shared/RealmConfiguration.cs) does have them. Those properties missing on the PCL class is a bug, and I have filed [an issue](https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet/issues/566).

Since the properties are actually there during runtime because Realm uses the [PCL bait and switch trick](http://log.paulbetts.org/the-bait-and-switch-pcl-trick/) you can set them using reflection until a fix comes out.

Comment: Yes I am using the PCL project. I give using reflection a try. Thanks for the advice

Comment: Using reflection did not work. Got exception "Set Method not found for 'EncryptionKey'". Do you know when the next release of Realm dotnet will be available, so I can pick up the change?

Comment: It seems the EncryptionKey property is there but does not seem to have a setter. The property CanWrite is set to false. Any ideas? Has anyone managed to get encryption working?

Comment: The property does have a setter - https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet/blob/V0.74.1/Realm.Shared/RealmConfiguration.cs#L80-L94. I'm not sure why reflection fails. Perhaps you can try the field instead?

We're preparing for a release in the next few days so the fix should be out soon.

Comment: I think it is a limitation of the PCL. Not all the features of reflection are supported. I will look forward to the new release. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was fixed in the v0.75.0 release